# R leaflet Cluster Markers

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

Not sure how to ask this question but I will just say what I want to do and see if it make sense.

I have 98 health centers that I want to display on a map. I want to some how communicate which patients (their geocoded home address) visited which particular location.

So what I am thinking what will be easier is to first map the 98 health centers all in different colours (so 98 different colours) an then map the patient geocoded home address as teh same colour corresponding to their respective health center.

Or is this possible...

After mapping the  98 health centers can the user be able to click a particular health center marker which produces clusters of patients that attended this location?

```
library(leaflet) 

lon<- c(-79.7040814, -79.7181073, -79.7205967, -79.6950229, 
        -79.7025451, -79.7101802, -79.697314,  -79.4193994, 
        -79.3616147, -79.4222632, -79.3799488, -79.436703,  
        -79.2605482)
lat<-c(44.3717399, 44.38451, 44.4009188,44.3953905,
       44.3395549,44.4074851,44.342504,43.6850894,
       43.6790897,43.7099293,43.6692283,43.6724314,
       43.8007403)

Clinic<-  c("green", "green", "green","green","green","green","green",
            "red", "red","red","red","red", "red")

test_df<- data.frame(lon,lat,Clinic)

icon_ClinicA <- makeAwesomeIcon(icon= 'hospital-o', markerColor = 'green', 
                                iconColor = 'white', library = "fa")
icon_ClinicB<- makeAwesomeIcon(icon = 'hospital-o', markerColor = 'red', 
                               iconColor = 'white', library = "fa")

leaflet(data=test_df) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat, 
              addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(lng=~lon, 
                        lat=~lat)) %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(color = ~Clinic, radius=2) %>% 
  addAwesomeMarkers(lng=-79.659507, lat=44.413486,
    label='Clinic A', icon = icon_ClinicA) %>% 
  addAwesomeMarkers(lng=-79.3939022, lat=43.6588712,
    label='Clinic B',icon = icon_ClinicB)
```

So to recap: the challenge I am facing is that I am trying to indicate which individual subjects come from a particular clinic. In this example it is easy to see, but however when I plot the rest of the 96 clinics, some clinics will be close in proximity to each other. Also, I tried to colour code the 98 clinics (in this case red vs green), but now thinking about it this might not be the safest route as there are not 98 different colours. Is it possible to have shades of a colour (i.e like in ggplot2)? So if possible could the Clinic A marker be one shade of red and Clinic B be a darker shade of red (with the corresponding subjects havgin matching colours to their respective clinics)?

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example we can work with to test out what you want to do? Meaning a dataframe we can copy/paste into R

Comment: Ok please see edits

Comment: Please `dput(data)`... What have you tried?